# Generalisation of Bertrand's postulate: not just one but two primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Just a sunday's question. Bertrand's postulate states that for every $n>1$, there is always at least one prime $p$ such that $n \lt p \lt 2n$.

Playing around with some small numbers suggests the question if there is possibly not just one but there are at least **two** primes in that interval.

From the following numerical example we can see that the answer seems to be affirmative for $n\ge6$

\begin{array}{ccc}
n&\{n-1,2n-1\}&\text{list of primes }p\\
 1 & \{0,1\} & \{\} \\
 2 & \{1,3\} & \{3\} \\
 3 & \{2,5\} & \{5\} \\
 4 & \{3,7\} & \{5,7\} \\
 5 & \{4,9\} & \{7\} \\
 6 & \{5,11\} & \{7,11\} \\
 7 & \{6,13\} & \{11,13\} \\
 8 & \{7,15\} & \{11,13\} \\
 9 & \{8,17\} & \{11,13,17\} \\
 10 & \{9,19\} & \{11,13,17,19\} \\
\end{array}

**Question**

I would greatly appreciate some references for this most probably well known result.

**EDIT**

Here I add some plots which show the number of primes between $n+1$ and $2n-1$ over different ranges of $n$.

I have fitted the curves with the function

$$b(n) = \frac{A n }{\log(1+B n)}$$

The parameters are shown in the plots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

*Discussion*

1. These graphs illustrate the proof of Erdös: "for any $k$ and sufficiently large $n$ there are always at least $k$ primes between $n$ and $2n$", as was pointed out in a comment of @lulu and in the solution of @Thomas Preu
2. The number $b(n)$ is not monotonous on a small scale.
3. The shape of the fitted functions is just what was to be expected from the [prime counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) $\pi(n)$. Indeed we have exactly just $b(n) = \pi(2n) - \pi(n)$.

Comment: I wouldn't know about exactly two for $n>6$, but it's clear from the Prime Number Theorem that the number of primes tends to $\infty$ with $n$. (So in particular there exists $N$ so $p\ge2$ for all $n>N$...)

Comment: More broadly, Erdos proved that, for any $k$ and sufficiently large $n$ there are always at least $k$ primes between $n$ and $2n$.  In practice, the bounds are fairly high, but often it's possible to simply check the finite number of possible exceptions.  See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) for links.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for your comment. See my edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [wikipedia on prime gaps](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds) there is a prime in every interval of the form $[x,x+x^{0.525}]$ for large enough $x\geq x_0$.

This implies immediately that $[n,2n]$ contains at least two primes for large enough $n\geq n_0$.

But this result seems to be nonexplicit about the bounds $x_0$ respectively $n_0$.

In a [paper of Dusart](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0442) you can find the explicit result (Proposition 6.8): there is a prime in every interval $\left(x,x\left(1+\frac{1}{25(\ln(x))^2}\right)\right]$ for $x\geq x_0=396738$.

The proof given there establishes this result only for $x\geq x_0'=3.8\cdot 10^6$. I guess the comparatively small gap between $x_0$ and $x_0'$ got checked numerically and the author doesn't even bother to mention it.

Since $1+\frac{1}{25(\ln(x))^2}$ is monotonically decreasing and $1+\frac{1}{25(\ln(x_0))^2}<1.00602<\sqrt{2}$ this implies your result for all $n\geq x_0$.

The $n<x_0$ can quickly be checked numerically. And it turns out to be true for $x_0>n\geq n_0=6$.

**Remarks:** As **lulu** pointed out in the comments, Dusart's result can be used to find for every $\epsilon>0$ and $k\geq 1$ an $x_{0,\epsilon,k}$ such that for all $x\geq x_{0,\epsilon,k}$ we have at least $k$ primes in $\left(x,\left(1+\epsilon\right)x\right]$.

Solving $1+\frac{1}{25(\ln(x))^2}=(1+\epsilon)^{1/k}$ we get $x_{0,\epsilon,k}=\max\left\{e^{\left((1+\epsilon)^{1/k}-1\right)^{-1/2}/5},x_0\right\}$.

This bound is actually fairly practical: It seems that only for $\epsilon$ and $k$ with $\frac{k}{\epsilon}\geq 10^4$ the bound $x_{0,\epsilon,k}$ starts to "explode".

These bounds are exponentially worse than what is expected to be true about prime gaps in conjectures (e.g. [Cramér's conjecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture)) that mathematicians seriously persue and that have been checked numerically at least up to $10^{19}$ (cf. [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.00499)).

Comment: @ Thomas Preu: Thank you for your valuable contribution. Solution accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a precise form of what you are looking for. Theorem 3.6 of [Das and Paul's 2019 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.09891.pdf) shows that

> For any integer $n$ and $k$, there are at least $k-1$ primes between
> $n$ and $kn$ when $n \ge 1.1\ln(2.5k) $